# Springwolf http://localhost:8080/springwolf/docs page 404

Tags: spring, asyncapi, springwolf

I am giving a try to [Springwolf](https://www.springwolf.dev/) to generate the documentation of my RabbitMQ Spring back-end code, and I managed to display the http://localhost:8080/springwolf/asyncapi-ui.html page.

**1. Problem**

The http://localhost:8080/springwolf/asyncapi-ui.html page only shows this:

```
Springwolf 

API VERSION - AsyncAPI JSON file

Servers
Channels

Semantics of publish and subscribe:

publish  means publish an event to the channel and this application will receive it
subscribe  means subscribe to this channel to receive events published by this application

Schemas
```

whereas **it should display a full list of info similar to this page**: https://demo.springwolf.dev/springwolf-ui/asyncapi-ui.html

**2. Investigation**

After investigating I noticed that the asyncapi-ui.html does an http request towards

```
http://localhost:8080/springwolf/docs
```

and this returns an "**HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**" !

It's as if this url was not handled by Springwolf.

I read the documentation https://www.springwolf.dev/docs/configuration/ and tried to change the url of the docs (I know it does break the Springwolf HTML UI, but I am just investigating to understand what's going on).

So I set this in application.yml:

```
springwolf:
  paths:
    docs: /springwolf/testdocs
```

and then I opened

```
http://localhost:8080/springwolf/testdocs
```

it does not work!
Also, in application yml, IntelliJ does underline "docs:" and a popup say:

```
cannot resolve configuration property 'springwolf.paths.docs'
```

I now deleted this springwolf.paths.docs parameter, but I wonder why, when I set it , I have this popup. Did this parameter changed ?

**3. Questions**

- How is that /springwolf-ui/asyncapi-ui.html page is displayed but /springwolf-ui/docs returns a 404.
  **How can I fix this 404?**
- Should I be worried about IntelliJ says "cannot resolve configuration property 'springwolf.paths.docs'" about "docs:' application yaml parameter?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: FYI, I reported this issue here: https://github.com/springwolf/springwolf-core/issues/348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that my project uses Spring Boot 2.7 & Spring 5, but **Springwolf requires Spring Boot 3 & Spring Framework 6**.

One can still use Springwolf with Spring Boot 2.7 and Spring 5 using some 'hack' (I managed to do so), but I would recommend to just use Spring Boot 3.

More info about that here:

- https://github.com/springwolf/springwolf-core/issues/348
- https://github.com/springwolf/springwolf-core/issues/478